# How to build proper CakePHP query for nested relations

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new with CakePHP, and i'm trying to build complicated query for results. It's killing me. Maybe some1 can help me here with that. **I'm using cake 2.7**

I have two tables with 3 relations (many to many). `Neighbourhood` and `Polygon`.
Case look like this `Neighbourhood` has many `Neighbourhoods` and it also belong to many `Neighbourhoods`. Also `Neighbourhood` has many `Polygons` and `Polygon` belong to many `Neighbourhoods`.

`Neighbourhood` table contains 2 fields `name` and `zip`. What i get from user is `zip code`.

And now what i want:
I want to get all `Polygons` from `Neighbourhood` and it's `Neighbours`. Where `Neighbourhood.zip = defined by user`.

How can i do that? Should i wrote custom query or divide proccess into smaller steps ? I am fighting with this all day.

Here is how models relations look likes:

```
class Neighbourhood extends AppModel
{
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Neighbourhoods' => array(
            'className' => 'Neighbourhood',
            'joinTable' => 'neighbourhoods_neighbours',
            'foreignKey' => 'neighbourhood_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'neighbour_id',
            'unique' => false
        ),
        'Polygon' => array(
            'className' => 'Polygon',
            'joinTable' => 'neighbourhoods_polygons',
            'foreignKey' => 'neighbourhood_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'polygon_id',
            'unique' => false
        ),
    );
}


class Polygon extends AppModel
{
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Neighbours' => array(
            'className' => 'Neighbourhood',
            'joinTable' => 'neighbourhoods_polygons',
            'foreignKey' => 'polygon_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'neighbourhood_id',
            'unique' => false,
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable containable behaviour in your models or even better once set it in you app model.

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

And then start to build up you queries e.g.

```
$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => '123'),
    'contain' => array(
        'Neighbourhood'=>array(
              'conditions' => array('Neighbourhood.id' => '123')
         )
     ),
     // or even joins
     'joins' => array(
          array(
                    'table' => $this->getTableName('default', 'neighbourhoods'),
                    'alias' => 'Neighbourhood',
                    'type' => 'RIGHT', // OR LEFT
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Neighbourhood.id = Polygon.neighbourhood_id',
                        'Neighbourhood.deleted' => 0,
                    )
          )
     )
 );

$polygons = $this->Polygon->find('all', $conditions);
```

If you think that this doesn't do enough (in order to do more complicated queries  ) then you would need to build up your query statements. e.g. running a query from Polygon model:

```
    $dbo = $this->getDataSource();
    $query = $dbo->buildStatement(
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Polygon.name AS polygon_name', 'Polygon.size',
                    'Neighbourhood.name AS neighbourhood_name', 'Neighbourhood.lat', 
                    'IF( Neighbourhood.created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) , 1 , 0) AS new_neighbourhood'  
                ), 
                'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this),
                'alias' => 'Polygon',
                'limit' => null,
                'offset' => null,
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => $this->getTableName('default', 'neighbourhoods'),
                        'alias' => 'Neighbourhood',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Neighbourhood.id = Polygon.neighbourhood_id',
                        ), 
                        'order' => 'Neighbourhood.name ASC',
                    ),
                    ....
                 ), 
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'group' => 'Polygon.name',
                'order' => 'Polygon.name ASC',
           ),
           $this
     );

 $polygons = $this->query($query);
```

And if you think even this is not enough then you have to sing amazing grace like this..

```
$polygons = $this->query("Here your sql query");

 debug($polygons);
```

Comment: i manage to create a query your way that worked, thanks for showing me a way

Comment: My pleasure. bare in mind this is for cakephp 2.x which you don't have much flexibility. But in cakephp 3.x which is ORM you are are free to do almost every thing much much simpler.

Comment: Framework and version wasn't my choice, it was client's choice. i do as i am told to.

Comment: I didn't mean Cakephp is bad. Cakephp is one of the best top frameworks. You can do a lot with it. best of luck